# Table with Special characters in column name in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to read JSON data(which is data from cassandra using Rest API). Below is JSON data I am getting :

```
[{"stud-id":104,"Mr.":"Krish","Mr/Ms":"Mr","dept_name":"CSE"}]
```

Below is my code in JQuery to read above JSON data into table :

```
         var stud_cols = [
         {
            id: "stud-id",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.int
        },
        {
            id: "Mr.",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        },{
            id: "Mr/Ms",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        },
        {
            id: "dept_name",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }];

        var studTable = {
            id: "stud",
            columns: stud_cols
        };

        schemaCallback([empTable,deptTable,studTable]);
    };

    // Download the data
    myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
                   $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/stud", function(resp) {
            var feat = resp,
                tableData = [];


                  if (table.tableInfo.id == "stud") {
            // Iterate over the JSON object
            for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
                tableData.push({
                   "stud-id": feat[i].$.escapeSelector( "stud-id" );,
                   "Mr.": feat[i].$.escapeSelector( "Mr." );,
                    "Mr/Ms": feat[i].$.escapeSelector( "Mr/Ms" );,
                    "dept_name":feat[i].dept_name,
                    });
            }
                 }
```

I was able to read other JSON sources where I don't have special characters in columns from JSON data.

I tried escapeselector but it is not working.Please help me to fix error in my code.

Comment: Can someone help me

Comment: reduce the amount of code to the core problem.

Comment: Issue got fixed after replacing with braces.below is new code                                                               
                    tableData.push({
                   "stud-id": feat[i]['stud-id'],
                   "Mr.": feat[i]['Mr.'],
     "Mr/Ms": feat[i]['Mr/Ms'],